# What has happend to my folder structure?

Tags: folder

For some reason, I can no longer see the folder structure in our Sharepoint site.

For example, for a project we have three top-level document libraries (top1, top2, and top3).
Inside top2, there are three Level 2 folders, L21, L22, and L23.
Folder L22 contains Doc1, Doc2, and Doc3, as well as a Level 3 folder, L31.
L31 contains Doc4 and Doc5.

Normally, if a user were to click Top2, they would see L21, L22, and L33.
If L22 were to be clicked, the user would see L31, Doc1, Doc2, and Doc3, and could upload docs to L22.
If L31 is clicked, the user would see Doc4 and Doc5 and could upload docs to L31.

That is what all users see when the folders are clicked.
Except me. When I click top2, I see L21, L22, L23, L31, Doc1, Doc2, Doc3, Doc4 and Doc5.
The path at the top of the page shows Project > top2.
If I click L22, I see everything again. The path at the top shows Project > top2 > L22.
If I try to upload a doc, the Upload Document page's subtitle is Upload Document : top2, but the path at the top of the page is Project > top2 > L22.
If I click L31, again I see everything and the path at the top shows Project > top2 > L22 > L31.

It is as if clicking on any library returns (for me) everything in that library, including folders, all flattened out. Clicking on any folder in the library changes the path at the top of the page, but everything in the library is displayed.

I have not created any personal views for the site, yet everyone else sees the folder/file structure as normal (using the All Documents view), but I see everything.

Could there be a personal view somewhere that I don't know about?
Anybody have any ideas how I can see the folder/file structure again?
(This happens in all project sites and in every document library).

Answer (score 1):

It definitely sounds like the view has "Folders or Flat: Show all items without folders" turned on.

Try creating a new view, based on standard, and seeing if you and other users get the right display. The AllItems.aspx view may have gotten corrupted somehow.

Try going to http://url/Forms/AllItems.aspx?contents=1 to see if there are any personal web parts on the page.

Answer (score 0):

The All Documents view has "Show items inside folders" on.

Everything looks fine to all users except me.
And this happens in all projects, including ones that appeared fine a couple days ago.

Adding "?contents=1" to the URL shows no personal web parts on any page.

Answer (score 0):

Got the anser, such as it is.
IE's cache was hosed. After clearing ALL history (including typed URLs), my display is back to normal.

Thanks, IE!